# Evitar duplicados en consulta SQL

Tags: sql-server

Estoy desarrollando en Sql Server2012.
tengo estas 4 tablas relacionadas como indica la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando estoy realizando una consulta me salen duplicados esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT C.ID_COTIZACION,G.ID_GENERA_PEDIDO,D.ID_DETALLE_COTIZACION FROM COTIZACION C
LEFT JOIN GENERA_PEDIDO G ON C.ID_COTIZACION=G.ID_COTIZACION
LEFT JOIN DETALLE_COTIZACION_CLIENTE D ON C.ID_COTIZACION=D.ID_COTIZACION
```

al ejecutar me sale duplicados como vemos en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano gracias por la antencion prestada y por la ayuda.

Espero este resultado de las 4 tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin duplicidad porque verificamos que hay 2 pedidos en la cotizacion y en el primer pedido solo hay 1 dato en detalle_genera_pedido de la 2 datos del detalle_cotizacion el otro null es que el producto no salio. lo que no quiero es que me salga duplicidad de los id como la imagen anterior gracias

Comment: ¿Qué resultado es el que esperas obtener? Por favor [incluye un ejemplo de la salida esperada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3794/21). Un saludo.

Comment: @Marioo, por favor edita tu pregunta, no dejes esa información en comentarios. Un saludo.

Comment: en tu ejemplo falta incluir los datos que hay en la tabla `detalle_genera_pedido`, sin esos es muy difícil ver como se deben relacionar unos con otros. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Has probado a usar la sentencia `DISTINCT` en tu consulta??

Prueba con la siguiente:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.ID_COTIZACION,G.ID_GENERA_PEDIDO,D.ID_DETALLE_COTIZACION FROM COTIZACION C
LEFT JOIN GENERA_PEDIDO G ON C.ID_COTIZACION=G.ID_COTIZACION
LEFT JOIN DETALLE_COTIZACION_CLIENTE D ON C.ID_COTIZACION=D.ID_COTIZACION
```

Espero que te funcione jejeje.

Un saludo compi

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no me funciona el distnict..